# How to run a .dll file on my linux web server

Tags: c#, php, linux

I have a dll file which was developed by C# . I want to use this dll file to run with my php version of application. I can run it locally with help of isapi extension in apache conf but was unable to run it on live server(Unix).
i would request to find me a solution.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot use mod_isapi .dll on a unix environment in a straightforward way & suggest you read this too where it states only WIN32 supported.

[Apache Manual](http://kypros.org/manual/mod/mod_isapi.html)

but there is a workaround for this by installing wine in your unix environment. Please visit the below thread to see the workaround.

http://forums.unigui.com/index.php?/topic/1328-can-i-run-dll-in-apache2-in-linux/